# Pagination is not working with the 2nd GridView that displays details of 1st GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want your help please.
I have a Gridview that display some data, and when I select a row, then the details of selected row will be in another Gridview, BUT Pagination is not working in this second Gridview !

*Note: each gridview is in a view*

For example :

```html
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View_1" runat="server">
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView_1"
                    ItemType="myApp.Models.DTO"
                    SelectMethod="GridView_1_GetData"
                    OnRowCommand="GridView_1_RowCommand"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    AllowPaging="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_prof" HeaderText="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Details.." HeaderText="Details" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:View>


            <asp:View ID="View_2" runat="server">                

                <h4>All Courses Of selected Prof</h4>

                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView_2"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    AllowPaging="true"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_2_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_course" HeaderText="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name_course" HeaderText="Course Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:Button ID="ReturnButton" Text="Go back to List" runat="server" OnClick="ReturnButton_Click" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```

Code Behind :

```cs
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<DTO> GridView_1_GetData()
    {
        ModelData db = new ModelData();

        var result = ..... a complex Linq query .....

        return result.OrderByDescending(c => c.Count);

    }


    protected void GridView_1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView_1.Rows[index];
            int idProf = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
            Details_Courses(idProf); /*** Call to Details_Courses function  ***/
            MultiView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
    }

    private void Details_Courses(int id)
    {
        ModelData db = new ModelData();

        var query = (from c in db.Courses                         
                     where c.id_prof == id
                     select new { c.id_course, c.name_course, c.description }).ToList();

        GridView_2.DataSource = query;
        GridView_2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView_2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView_2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView_2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ReturnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

*Note: this is just an example - profs & Courses . BUT I have another database*

Comment: How many rows are coming back from the query in the Details_Courses method? And how many you want per page on GridView 2?

Comment: 1- Several rows... Sometimes more than ten. 2- I want ten (by default) per page. (this is just an example - profs & Courses . BUT I have another concept)

Comment: Is there someone who has ideas for this problem, please ?

Comment: You should try doing server side paging. Only return what is required to display on a page. At the moment you are returning all records which satisfies the condition. Think if the query has million records in result, your page will take a long time to load. So try server side paging.